# change custom height width of all images from product in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.1

i have 3 images for specific product. all images are of different sizes. so i want all images in same height width while getting. i can resize image using resize function but its resizing only specific image not all.
currently i am using this its giving me image size only for product base image. but i want for all

```
$this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image' )->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepFrame(TRUE)->resize(270, 340)->getUrl()
```

but i am using

```
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); 

if ($images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                if ($image->getMediaType() == 'image') {
                    $productImagesArray[] = $image->getUrl();
                } elseif ($image->getMediaType() == 'external-video') {
                    $videoUrl = (!empty($image->getVideoUrl())) ? $image->getVideoUrl() : $image->getVideoUrlDefault();
                }
            }
        }
```

i want to resize all images from this for loop with given height width

Answer (score 0):

Can u create a function to resize and call that function passing param as  'product_base_image' with 'product_small_image'